# highlight a column on table element - CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, react-bootstrap-table

I have a table constructed in the following format:

```
<thead>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to highlight a column if the header column is hovered.  So let's say if I hovered the second header `<th> from`, say blue, then the second `<td>` from every `<tr>`, which makes it a column, will be highlighted in yellow.  How can I achieve this? I've tried many different ways but its not highlighting the `<tr>`, only the header.  I would like to keep it in a table structure.  Can anybody help with this?

Comment: You would need js for this because there is no parent css selector so you couldn't tell cells in an other row that a header cell has been hovered

Comment: Take a look https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/row-and-column-highlighting/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Comment: the links look like it applies to one color, but the header and body cells of columns are separate colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <th>head 1</th>
  <th>head 2</th>
  <th>head 3</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 2</td>
    <td>row 1 cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 2</td>
    <td>row 2 cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3 cell 1</td>
    <td>row 3 cell 2</td>
    <td>row 3 cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
```

and css

```
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}


td, th {
  position: relative;
}
th:hover {background-color:blue;}

th:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't this apply  only one color.  The header and the body cells are separate colors.  So header will be blue and the cells underneath it are gray

Comment: i have edited my code above to have a different colour for the rows and header